# BizTalk 2009 DB2 HIS Adapter

Tags: db2, biztalk, biztalk-2009

When using the mainframe DB2 adapter for Microsoft BizTalk 2009, is there any way to get the generated schema to contain all the columns in the result set?

We get a simple schema generated, the response contains a record/element called "ResultSets" with a data structure of 'xs:anyType'.

If I recall, this works okay in MS/SQL server stored procs (but memory is shakey - I think we had to change add the "for xml auto" to the select statement while doing the generate data).

Would any other adapter work?  What about the new WCF/LOB adapters?

---

Here's another summary of this issue that I just found: 
http://www.novaenterprisesystems.com/Blog/category/Adapters.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted that question in MSDN forum for HIS, and they said it doesn't do that.  I think the DB2 interface is very un-baked and un-tested. You also have to set the response schema to "Unqualified", but seems like the request schema's "element form default?" has to be "qualified, thus resulting in two different schemas - i.e. you have to split the schema that they generate into two.